# TaskFactory changing parameters

Tags: c#, multithreading, taskfactory

So i have the following code:

```
public void tViewers(int? start, int? stop)
    {
        for (int? i0 = start; i0 <= stop; i0++)
        {
            StartLabel:
            Viewer v = new Viewer(channelNameTextBox.Text, this);
            if (urlWithTokens.Contains(v.getViewerLink()))
            {
                goto StartLabel;
            }
            else
            {
                if (v.getViewerLink() != "")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("[V #" + i0 + "] SUCCESS");
                    urlWithTokens.Add(v.getViewerLink());
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Channel not found.");
                    showError("The channel name is not valid.", true);
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => this.botControlls.Enabled = true));
                    urlWithTokens.Clear();
                }
            }
            v = null; // clear
        }
        Console.WriteLine("[V] " + start + " to " + stop + " COMPLETED");
        start = null;
        stop = null;
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
```

Which is executed by:

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxThreads; i++)
        {
             taskFactory.StartNew(() => tViewers(someValue, someHigherValue));
        }
```

The problem here is the local parameters "start" and "stop" in tViwers and it returst some stange values.

fx if i print "start" it should return the "someValue" and "someHigherValue" depending on what "thread" it is running in, however it returns strange values 40, 50 or something (even if it should return 1, 2, 3...

I have tried using the GC.SuppressFinalize(this); and setting the int's to null my allowing them to be null (int?). However the problem is still there...

Can someone help me?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your problem. Can you give us a short example that reproduces your problem? I suspect it has something to do with the creation of a closure and the capturing of your variables.. but I can't be sure.

Comment: If i run: 
taskFactory.StartNew(() => tViewers(0, 5));

It should return:
[V # 0] SUCCESS
[V # 1] SUCCESS
[V # 2] SUCCESS
[V # 3] SUCCESS
[V # 4] SUCCESS


But it returns:
[V #30] SUCCESS

Comment: it seems to change the parameters. I think it has something to do with the TaskFactory but i dont know..

Comment: I found something at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963549.aspx but cant seem to figure our when i give it parameters with it.

Comment: I figured it out, creating var tmp for the parameters got the job done, if anyone else have the issue, look at msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963549.aspx

Comment: Thats exactly what I thought.. an issue with closures capturing your variables. This is well documented.